# Apache Phoenix and zookeeper port mapping

Tags: hbase, port, apache-zookeeper, apache-phoenix

I am trying to connect to a remote `Phoenix` server on a cluster where almost all the ports are locked.

By ssh-ing to the master and mapping 2181 for `zookeeper`, I succeed to connect to the hbase server on that cluster. (= `status` command in `hbase shell` works properly)

But, when I am trying to connect to the phoenix server remotely it hangs and prints no error messages:

```
$ ./sqlline.py localhost
Setting property: [isolation, TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED]
issuing: !connect jdbc:phoenix:localhost none none org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
Connecting to jdbc:phoenix:localhost
15/10/07 16:00:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I have already confirmed that a local Phoenix on the cluster is working fine. So, I conclude server configuration is correct.

I am wondering if Phoenix is using any ports other than zookeeper port.

Comment: instead of using localhost try to give the ip address of the zookeeper and port

Comment: same result. the 2181 port (zookeeper port) on the remote machine is locked. So, what I am doing to connect to that port is using ssh -L to map remote port to my localhost. It works for hbase shell, but not the Phoenix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigation, I found that the region server ports (16020 in hbase 1+ and 60020 in hbase 0.98) was not open in that environment.

The reason that it was working for hbase shell, is hbase shell connect to a region server when it is needed (when a region on that region server is queried), but phoenix connect to all of them at first.

Comment: Great find, we had a similar firewall issue